# Most efficient way in mysql for taking average after deduplication

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have a table A with columns: (id, item, price). It has records like

| id | item | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | banana | 1 |
| 2 | banana | 1 |
| 3 | apple | 2 |

I want to calculate the average price after deduplication based on the item column. In the example that I just gave, the average should be (1 + 2)/ 2 = 1.5.

There is a simple-minded way of doing this:

`SELECT AVG(price) FROM (SELECT MIN(price) FROM A GROUP BY item)`

However in reality I have a huge table so it is not realistic to do the select subquery first. I wonder whether there is any hack around this.

Comment: What about a case where you have banana 1, banana? Would that be a duplicate? Also, how big is your table so as to be concerned with size? How often is this query going to be executed?

Comment: the same item will always have the same price. It is in the size of ten of billions and it is updated daily.

Comment: But I guess different items can have the same price? I think you will need a subquery or a CTE. Why do you think that is "not realistic"? What should this mean? Did you try out and observed a poor performance? Even if there is any trick to avoid the subquery, this will very likely have the identic performance because the requirement to fetch a distinct price per item is the same.

Comment: If there aren't many duplicates, you could just exclude their ids from the select. Otherwise, I think you're stuck with a subquery. Don't know if 'SELECT DISTINCT item, price from A' as your subquery would be any faster. You could try dumping the whole file to csv and running an application on it to get the average, but this might not be any faster either. Maybe you should consider getting rid of duplicates, then it's easy.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `AVG()` window function after deduplication:

```
SELECT DISTINCT AVG(MAX(price)) OVER () AS avg_price
FROM tablename
GROUP BY item;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/u7zQPx1U).

Comment: I checked to see if the index proposed in my answer for item and price would help this. The optimizer did not use the index, unfortunately. Overall, the performance seems similar to using a subquery. I am +1 because this is just FYI.

Answer (score 0):

Outside of deduplicating this per some of the comments, one approach is to add an index on both `item` and `price`. With one million rows, time to execute is reduced from ~0.85 s to 0 s.

```sql
SELECT AVG(price)
FROM (
    SELECT MIN(price) price
    FROM A
    GROUP BY item
) t;

--  1 row(s) returned   0.875 sec / 0.000 sec

ALTER TABLE A ADD INDEX itemPriceIndex (item, price)
--  0 row(s) affected Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0    1.891 sec

SELECT AVG(price)
 FROM (
  SELECT MIN(price) price
     FROM A
     GROUP BY item
 ) t
-- 1 row(s) returned    0.000 sec / 0.000 sec
```

Data generation code (only 100,000 rows generated below but timings above were 1,000,000 rows):

```sql
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS stackOverflow;
CREATE DATABASE stackOverflow;
USE stackOverflow;

CREATE TABLE A (
   id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   item VARCHAR(20),
   price INT,
   PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

DROP PROCEDURE if EXISTS generateData;
delimiter #
CREATE PROCEDURE generateData(in nReps int)
BEGIN
    DECLARE v_counter int unsigned DEFAULT 0;
    
    TRUNCATE TABLE A;
    START transaction;
    while v_counter < nReps DO
        INSERT INTO A (item, price) VALUES ("banana", 1);
        SET v_counter = v_counter + 1;
    END WHILE;
    INSERT INTO A (item, price) VALUES("apple", 2);
    COMMIT;
END #
delimiter ;
CALL generateData(100000);
```

Comment: The benefit of an index depends on 2 factors: 1) how many tuples per item there are. Some textbooks talk about 5% as the threshold at which the DBMS would do a sequential scan instead of using an index; and 2) how smart the planer in mysql is.

Try using EXPLAIN <yourquery> 

to see if it uses the index.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is unlikely that the DBMS will deduplicate. So your question is misleading. the DBMS will scan a table a create a list of unique values.

If you want to improve the performance of this query, you need to look at the statistics of how this query is performed.

1. This query can only be answered with at least one pass. Unless you have extra constructs (like a table that gets updated with a trigger), the DMBS needs to read every tuple to find: a) the different values of item, and b) the minimum price for each. In other words, the fastest time this query can be answered (even in the presence of indices) is the time it takes to do a `select * from table;`
2. This query requires space proportional to the number of different values of item (this number is stored in the statistics). If there is not enough memory in the DBMS to store all these different values and their minimum, a temp table will be created in disk.
3. If there is not enough memory for all the different tuples, the query will start to degrade because it needs to do some sorting (effectively turning your O(n) query into a O(nlogn).

so, if I were you, I would:

1. Inspect the plan that the DBMS uses to answer the query and make sure it is linear in the retrieval of the tuples (a sequential scan). Use EXPLAIN to do this.
2. If it is not, it is most likely due to lack of memory. Can you increase it?
3. If none works, you need to think of a different schema to solve this query (a trigger can keep the minimum value for each item in a table with little overhead).